# WordPress deployment for multiple websites and countries

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a website e.g `www.mysite.com` and it content is in english. Now I need a feature which allows users to choose their residing country and directly take them to URL something like `www.mysite.com/en/US`. My questions:

1. How do I do the redirection from one url to another ?
2. Can I customize that the `www.mysite.com/en/US` will have more or less pages ?
3. How do I implement language selection for this scenario ?
4. Do I need more than one WordPress installation for this ?

Any tips or references is most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download http://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate/, it's free and very easy. 
It detect language from browser and you just need to set default language

see also http://www.wpmayor.com/best-wordpress-multilanguage-plugins/ for more info.